# Excel INDEX MATCH MATCH combined with SUMPRODUCT?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to update a proposal/pricing table for internal job costing. Our project leads estimate hours by employee by month and then a rate gets applied to that estimate to come up with a total price. Not every job will use every employee.

| Employee/Hours | Jan/21 | Feb/21 | Mar/21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 10 | 15 | 20 |
| Jane Doe | 20 | 20 | 10 |

The rate table lives in another tab and lists all employees in column A, and their hourly rate per month in columns B onward, with the same date headers as the hours estimate. The rate table may include months earlier or later than the months on the hours tab as well.

| Rate Table | Dec/21 | Jan/21 | Feb/21 | Mar/21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | $12 | $12 | $12 | $13 |
| Jim Doe | $13 | $13 | $13 | $13 |
| Jane Doe | $12 | $12 | $13 | $13 |

In the past, I've had the hours table at the top of the hours estimate tab, and then another table directly below that uses INDEX MATCH MATCH to find the appropriate rate by employee by month and then multiply that by the hours for that employee above. It works, but then it means that I have to show the total cost for each employee, by month, which I really don't need to do. I'd love to just have a line under each month column with the total cost for that month, while avoiding writing the formula many times

```
=(B2 * INDEXMATCHMATCH)+(B3 * INDEXMATCHMATCH)+(B4 * INDEXMATCHMATCH)
```

[obviously this isn't the real formula, because it would be super long].
Is there a way to multiply hours in column B by the associated rate for those employees for that month and sum it together in one cell?

| Employee/Hours | Jan/21 | Feb/21 | Mar/21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 10 | 15 | 20 |
| Jane Doe | 20 | 20 | 10 |
| *Total Cost* | $360 | $380 | $390 |

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way I think you'll be willing to try:

```
=SUM(XLOOKUP($G$2:$G3,$A$2:$A$4,INDEX($B$2:$E$4,,MATCH(H$1,$B$1:$E$1,0)))*H$2:H$3)
```

(I found a few ways, some interesting, but they are longer, written out, than this formula and you seem comfortable with the `INDEX/MATCH` approach so it would probably be easy for you to use and to maintain.)

So, for the formula as written, I copied your data tables to A1:E4 for the "Rate Table" and G1:J3 for the "Employee/Hours" table. The addressing in the formula works for those ranges. You'll want to adjust for that to fit your exact situation.

**Read through to the end:  Do not be disturbed that I am foolishly talking about an output table.** (I only noticed when re-reading question and answer that you wished to have the results under the "Employee/Hours" table's data lines.) The formula above works for that desire as I fixed the references I made while generating a formal output table, so you can just paste in as needed.)

To build the output table, I just used formulas like `=H1` to fill in the output tables' left and top headers (names and months). Those will obviously be known to you and therefore be easy to adjust as needed for any calculation you set up. Similarly, I used bog standard `=SUM(M2#)` summing formulas which have the advantage of not needing adjustment since they refer to the entire SPILL arrays the formulas in the first row produce.

The real difficulty for all the approached I tried was I would end up with a formula that had **TWO** SPILL arrays in its final output and Excel does NOT reward such things. Because they had distinct uses in each, I could not finesse them into a single SPILL array that would let you have a single formula in the upper left cell of the block of cells making up the cost region of the output table. After deciding to do the SPILL arrays down rather than across, I was ready for the "meat" of the problem, those monthly costs per employee.

For the "meat" as one might say, the dollar cost per month for each employee in any given job, you use the formula.

First the `INDEX/MATCH`:  (first month column for now) it matches the output table's months to the "Rate Table" columns and finds that column 2 of the dollar region is needed. INDEX-ing the dollar region gives gives an output array size of one column by three rows which corresponds to the outer `XLOOKUP()`'s one column by three row lookup array. If they did not match up like that, you'd get an error. So then the `XLOOKUP()` seeks the name of the employee, for which you use an array (`$L2#` in this case) to get outputs for all the employees listed in the output table. These SPILL downwards, as desired.

Next, copy the formula to each column of the output table and your costs for all employees each month fill in and the sums update.

(By the way, your example output's sum for "Feb/21" is incorrect which is why the formula generates $440 (15*$12=$180, 20*$13=$260, $180+$260=$440 instead of $380.)

So, to make the fix, I just needed to select the first formula I had in the output table, press `F2-Edit`, highlight and copy the formula, then move to the "Employee/Hours" table, first empty row after the hours data, and type "=SUM(", paste in the formula I copied, type ")", and press Enter. After adjusting the references to match the data in the "Employee/Hours" table, the cell had a sum of the information calculated for the unneeded output table. Copying the cell and pasting to the right gave the output you desire.

A last thought:  that did not help in being able to use one SPILL array across the total cost cells. Sad to say. You'll still need to copy and paste into however many columns are being used.